# Uniqueness of difference between powers of 2 and 3

Tags: nt.number-theory

Is there a simple proof (accessible with high school math only) that there is only one solution to: $d=3^k-2^n$, for integers $k,n$, with $n$ being the largest integer for which $d>0$? In other words, a proof that any such power difference is unique.

Comment: I found this related post on math.SE: [How prove this diophantine equation $3^x-2^y=k$ have finitely many integral solutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/834551). (I searched [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24d%3D3%5Ek-2%5En%24&p=1).)

Comment: why off topic?? this is a pretty hard question well in the research interests of many people here.

Comment: @Dror, in that case, the single word, "No," would be an answer to the question as stated.